# How to refresh a method in Rails model on data update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method in my Transaction model which calculates sum of data from Transactions table:

```
def self.total_amount
 sum('amount')
end
```

It is displayed in the view

```
<%= Transaction.total_amount %>
```

After the data is refreshed (new transactions added) the sum stays the same. How do I make it recalculate itself?

Thanks

Comment: Since I have no idea what to try, I did not try anything!

Comment: "After the data is refreshed (new transactions added) the sum stays the same" implies you tried something. Do you mean you want the total amount to update in the view without refreshing the page?

Comment: The idea is to use JavaScript.  Here's some good reading that will help: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: @DamienRoche Nono, no Javascript, the problem is that my SUM doesn't update at all, even after I refresh the page. It only updates after I restart the server.

Comment: What about if you do `lambda { sum('amount') }.call` from within the `total_amount` method?

Comment: Yay lambda worked. Please post this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def self.total_amount
  lambda { sum('amount') }.call
end
```

Though, as touched on in the comments, I have no idea why you're experiencing such behaviour. I've checked in a production environment and I receive no such problem.

Comment: how is a class method with no dynamic content : `sum('amount')` cached?

Comment: @tihom counter question: can you explain how the lambda fixed the issue for the OP? I don't claim to have all the answers. I figured it was a similar issue to the scopes being evaluated on env load because I recently ran into the same problem myself. If you have some wisdom to share, then please share it!

Comment: AFAIK `def self.total_amount sum('amount') end` should not be cached. The code inside a method is evaluated run-time. You can check by defining a class method: `def self.test; puts Time.now; end`. It would print current time every time it is run. I think something else is going on in OP's code.

Comment: @tihom you're correct. Silly of me to draw a false correlation.  I'll update the answer so as to not spread bad information. In this case, I'm completely baffled.